# OEM Install ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I could no longer find the OEM option on the installation of Ubuntu 18.04. This is correct (normally this was always under F4)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming installation from a USB drive:
Insert USB drive containing Ubuntu install files.
Boot the machine and press the appropriate key/combination (depends on manufacturer) to take you to boot options menu.
Use the arrow keys to select the USB drive and press Return, then immediately press and hold Shift.
You will be presented with a list of options:

Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Check disc for defects